# RxJava: Dynamic set of observables

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a central class, call it `Central`.  It can have 1-N observables added to it.  These I need to add dynamically, and then know when the final onComplete() has executed.

How to do this?

Code sample:

```
public class Central {
  public void addObservable(Observable o){
    // Add the new observable to subscriptions
  }
}
```

---

**Update.**

I've been going around on this one a while.  Using @DaveMoten's answer, I've gotten close.

Here is my method to add a new observable at will, and be notified when all of them have completed (pseudo-code):

```
class central {
  PublishSubject<Observable<T>> subject = PublishSubject.create();
  int commandCount = 0;
  int concatCount = 0;
  addObservable(Observable newObs){
    commandCount++;
    concatCount++;
    subject.concatMap(o -> 
          o.doOnCompleted(
                  () -> { 
                    concatCount--;
                    LOG.warn("inner completed, concatCount: " + concatCount);
                  })
          ).doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .doOnCompleted(() -> { 
                System.out.println("OUTER completed");
            } ) .subscribe();

    onNext(newObs);
    subject.onCompleted(); // If this is here, it ends prematurely (after first onComplete)
    // if its not, OUTER onComplete never happens

    newObs.subscribe((e) ->{},
    (error) -> {},
    () -> {
        commandCount--;
        LOG.warn("inner end: commandCount: " + commandCount);
    });
  }
}
// ... somewhere else in the app:
Observable ob1 = Observable.just(t1);
addObservable.addObservable(ob1);
// ... and possibly somewhere else:
Observable ob2 = Observable.just(t2, t3);
addObservable(ob2);

// Now, possibly somewhere else:
ob1.onNext(1);
// Another place:
ob2.onNext(2);
```

The logging looks like so:

```
19:51:16.248 [main] WARN  execute: commandCount: 1
19:51:17.340 [main] WARN  execute: commandCount: 2
19:51:23.290 [main] WARN  execute: commandCount: 3
9:51:26.969 [main] WARN   inner completed, concatCount: 2
19:51:27.004 [main] WARN  inner end: commandCount: 2
19:51:27.008 [main] WARN  inner completed, concatCount: 1
19:51:27.009 [main] WARN  inner end: commandCount: 1
19:51:51.745 [ProcessIoCompletion0] WARN  inner completed, concatCount: 0
19:51:51.750 [ProcessIoCompletion0] WARN  inner completed, concatCount: -1
19:51:51.751 [ProcessIoCompletion0] WARN  inner end: commandCount: 0
19:51:51.752 [ProcessIoCompletion0] WARN  inner completed, concatCount: -2
19:51:51.753 [ProcessIoCompletion0] WARN  inner completed, concatCount: -3
```

UPDATE: I added some counters, that demonstrate I don't understand what is happening with concatMap.  You can see the lambda subscribe on the observers itself count down to 0 correctly, but the concatMap oncomplete goes down to -3!  And OUTER complete never happens.

Comment: When you say prematurely what do you mean? I don't see the problem. I ran a test and it printed `1, inner completed, 2, 3, inner completed, outer completed`. That's just the ticket.

Comment: @DaveMoten The problem is this is in a method with an indeterminate number of new observables coming in.  I can't call onComplete like that, because it causes the subject to finish, even if new observables have been added.  Updated example to try to make more clear.

Comment: That's fine. It is ok never to call `subject.onCompleted()`!

Comment: By the way you cannot make `ob1.onNext` and `ob2.onNext` calls. That is only possible on a `Subject`. Are you sure you don't want the inner observables to be `Subject`s as well (and use `flatMap` instead of `concatMap`)?

Comment: I'm testing and if subject.onCompleted() isn't called, the OUTER complete never seems to happen (the system is fairly complex but that does appear to be the case!)

Comment: @DaveMoten Another update to question, with counters added to help debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `PublishSubject`:

```
PublishSubject<Observable<T>> subject = 
    PublishSubject.create();
subject
    // protect against concurrent calls to subject (optional)
    .serialize()
    .concatMap(o -> 
      o.doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("inner completed")))
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
    .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("completed"))
    .subscribe(subscriber);

subject.onNext(Observable.just(t1));
subject.onNext(Observable.just(t2, t3));
subject.onCompleted();

  .
```

Comment: That almost does what I'm looking for... that part that isn't is, `doOnCompleted` only fires if I manually call it with `subject.onCompleted()`.  I want to get an onComplete when the source observables have fired onComplete.

Comment: I can almost get there with `observable.doOnCompleted(subject::onCompleted);` but that only works for a single source observable.  How to do it for multiple sources?

Comment: Easily done by adding `doOnCompleted` to `o` inside the `concatMap`. I modified the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I accepted this because I thought that was it... but what I'm looking for is to be notified when all the internal observables have executed onComplete... is that possible?

Comment: The final `doOnCompleted` above will not be called till all the internal observables have been completed.

Comment: I think I'm not implementing your solution just right.  I updated the question... mind taking a look?